# Abort entire application from thread in delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have a major problem with my delphi App.  I'm developing a software that uses external security. I'm using usb devices that must be connected to the users machine in order for my software to run. If by any chance the user removes this dongle, or starts without it, the app is supposed to warn the user and stop immediately.
A thread is being released at the creation of the app, which checks for the security device. However, when the checks fail, e.g. no device found, that thread is not killing my app. I'm using something like this:

```
    retCode := checkSecurity();
    if retCode = -1 then
    begin
        ShowMessage('Security device not found! Terminating immediately!');
        Application.Terminate;
    end;
```

The major problem here is that `Application.Terminate` doesn't really kill the app. I've read on SO and other places that the Terminate sends a signal for a gracefull shutdown and waits for other threads, in my case the main thread of the app, to finish. I really need to kill the app as mentioned, killing all threads and exiting, if possible, cleaning up to avoid memory leakage, but if not, fine with me.  I'm using Delphi XE2, developing with Windows 8.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: "cleaning up to avoid memory leakage" This is the reason why `Application.Terminate` works in this manner - to make sure things get cleaned up.

Comment: This app I"m developing is going to be commercialized, so if someone tries to use the software w/o its security device, I don't really mind to leave some leftovers, as long as the app gets shutdown

Comment: Abruptly closing of any application is never a good idea. Why? Becouse doing so could even lead to data damage.For instance lets us say that at the time of termination your application is writing some data to disn and its is only half finished. Abruptly closing it at this time would mean that haf of the data that should have been written would be forever gone.

Comment: Now you say that you don't care what your aplication causes when someone tries to use it in improper way. But in how many scenarios your application might think that it is used in improper way tu it isn't. For instance you could have legitimate user which is having problems with USB controller so every now and then your application might detect as your security device being pluged out. Would you realy want to cause haveoc for such user every time. Or what about the case when USB controller might get powered down due to Power Saving (computer entering sleep mode).

Comment: FYI, `Application.Terminate()` posts a `WM_QUIT` message to the message queue of the *calling thread*, and `Application.Run()` in the main thread looks for that message to exit when received. If you call `Terminate()` in a worker thread, `Run()` will never get the message. So have the worker thread use `PostThreadMessage(MainThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0)` instead. You might also consider doing an initial security check in the main thread at startup before starting anything else. Exit the app immediately if the check fails, otherwise finish starting up and create the thread for subsequent checks.

Comment: Calling `ShowMessage` from a worker thread is wrong.  The VCL is not thread safe.

Comment: I did try to do the check at startup, but the process slowed down significantly the startup, leaving the user experience quite bad. But I see now what SilverWarrior meant, I'm studying the possibility to switch to a more cleaner and safer way to do this.

Comment: The message displayed using `ShowMessage` must be blocking. I tried using `Application.MessageBox` but this method is not blocking, causing the code after it to be executed, which is something that I don't wanna. Is there anything else, native to delphi, that I could use to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`ExitProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682658.aspx) to force immediate termination. In comparison to `Halt`, the OS function `ExitProcess` performs even less clean up.

Comment: `ExitProcess` worked like a charm! As I mentioned, my software and finnancial security comes first, later on I'll try working on improvements for the leakage. Thanks David!!!

Comment: You won't leak anything. The OS tidies up for you.

Answer (score 2):

To kill an app, just call [Halt](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Halt). It's a leftover from the DOS times, adapted to work nicely with modern Delphi apps. It will call all 'finalization' blocks in all units but not much more.

Comment: Using Halt raises an Exception `System Error Code 5: Access Denied`

Comment: That's surely because something in your code is being executed at termination. Use of a debugger would tell you what it is. Either deal with why that code is raising an error, or bypass it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

To terminate application from a thread you may use:

```
TThread.Queue(nil, 
  procedure
  begin
    Application.Terminate;
  end
);
```

Which is cross-platform and is "almost" the same as

```
PostThreadMessage(MainThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
```

given that the Application object was not destroyed already and you use Windows.